# Using an HLists as an arguments to a function

Tags: scala, shapeless

Is it possible to pass an HList as a function parameter?

This is what I have so far:

```
import shapeless._
import poly._

object id extends (Id ~> Id) {
  def apply[T](f: shapeless.Id[T]): shapeless.Id[T] = f
}

object ListHandler {
  def mapOverHlist[ListType <: HList](list: ListType) = list.map(id)
}

val x = "foo" :: "bar" :: 0xb33f :: HNil    
ListHandler.mapOverHlist(x)
```

Leads to this error:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter mapper:   
shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper[ShapelessSpec.this.id.type,ListType]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Error text contains solution:

```
import shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper

def mapOverHlist[L <: HList](list: L)(implicit m: Mapper[id.type, L]): m.Out =
  list.map(id)
```

Method `map` accepts an implicit parameter and you should provide such parameter (by adding the same parameter to declaration of your method).